# How can I send a welcome email to a user AFTER they login for the first time?

Tags: login, email

What I want to do is after a user creates an account... they log in for the first time it will kick off a welcome email to the user that will give them an overview of the site and suggestions of what they should do to get the most out of the site.

I'm not sure where this would go... any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom usermeta for `has_logged_in` or something like that and then check it  when the user logs in to see if it exists and is properly set. If so, no email sent, otherwise, email sent. You could take the opposite approach and create usermeta for `not_has_logged_in` or something like that and then check that on login to see if it exists and if it does, email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this welcome pack plugin for new user accounts.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-pack/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a plugin that allows you to do that, you can check out [Profile Builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/), two of its features being email confirmation and email customization.